# RoR Encryption and Decryption for query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, encryption

I've been searching for the past few days about encrypting some data to use on the URL.

I basically have 3 strings and i need to encrypt then on a unique token.

eg: code: '12345678' email: 'teste@encrypt.com' name: 'nameTest'

This will be join together as code%email%name and i need to encrypt them.

What's the best way to do it as i need to pass the encrypted string on the  URL for the other server to decrypt? The algorithms i've used all put some form of '/\=' and i guess that probably may cause problems

Thanks for the help

Comment: Nope, those won't cause any problems if you url-escape the resulting string. You try encode/decode here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: Do you mean "encrypt" as in "prevent people from seeing the contents" or do you mean "encode" as in "make it so I can pass these around"? The simplest encoding is often base64. Joining with `%` will be trouble since it's a huge assumption that these fields will not contain that.

Answer (score 1):

In 2019, `URI.encode` is obsolete and should not be used

If you want safely put encrypted string into url without problems with special characters then you could use `CGI.escape`or `ERB::Util.url_encode` for this purpose.

```
require 'erb'

ERB::Util.url_encode("Hello world")
#=> "Hello%20world"
```

Rails will decode automatically when receiving

If you want something simple that encodes and hide raw data which could be decoded somewhere later and verified then you could use `MessageVerifier` provided by active support:

```
@verifier = ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier.new('s3Krit')
cookies[:remember_me] = @verifier.generate([@user.id, 2.weeks.from_now])
id, time = @verifier.verify(cookies[:remember_me])
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html
http://ngauthier.com/2013/01/rails-unsubscribe-with-active-support-message-verifier.html

If you want true encryption then you could look into such project. It uses OpenSSL:
http://rocketjob.github.io/symmetric-encryption/